# Tool to show DNA sequence and allowing upload of own graph data

Tags: genome, sequence-analysis, visualization

**Background**

We want to be able to load (or request) data for a genome including the sequence and gene annotation (bacteria). Then, we want to load our own annotation which should be displayed as a line plot:

```
position score
1        5
2        6
etc.
```

Where each position corresponds to the position in the genome (i.e. FASTA).
Something like this:

[image]

**Question**

Is there a tool that can load a genome sequence, gene annotation, and a position ~ score file, which can be displayed as a line plot?

Comment: Welcome to the site. In order to suggest a good alternative could you comment what do you need this tool for? Why do you need to display the gene annotation? What is the problem with IGV ? (I found the sentence a bit confusing, perhaps if you rephrase it I'll understand it)

Comment: I thought I was clear regarding what I need it for: uploading genome + annotation + own data (position + score). Why gene annotation? Because we want to look whether the the line plot we upload differs between genes and intergenic regions. Just similar as a GC plot beneath the genes and intergenic regions but then with own supplied scores per position. Indeed, I forgot a word in my sentence about IGV @Llopis

Comment: I don't find this question useful. It only helps people who find IGV ugly. Also you don't seem to have researched for other options like [IGB](https://bioviz.org/). Have a nice day!

Comment: A local tool is fine, with upload I meant uploading it to a tool (perhaps not the best word choice). The screenshot is from a tool which only visualizes a Listeria genome (no other bacteria), but I liked the interface. Currently I'm trying to use IGB @terdon

Answer (score 1):

You can use UCSC genome browser, which supports custom genome sequence and annotation. Specifically, one needs to create a [Track Hub](https://genome.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/help/hgTrackHubHelp.html) to hold genomes and annotations.

Here is an example:

> http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?hubUrl=http://zlab-trackhub.umassmed.edu/yfu/insects/hub.txt&db=hub_129615_cl_v0.8.2

And here is the corresponding [hub.txt](http://zlab-trackhub.umassmed.edu/yfu/insects/hub.txt) file holding the metadata, and URLs to actual fasta, bigWig and bigBed files.